# Get 2 isolated instances of a python module

Tags: python

I am interacting with a python 2.x API written in a non-OO way, it uses module-global scope for some internal state driven stuff. It's needed in a context where it's no longer singleton, and modifying the original code (not ours) is not an option.

Short of using subprocess runs of separate interpreters, is there any way I could box off the modules and interact with multiple instances of the module (thus treating it as an object)?

I need to use the module to drive 2 different setups - which it doesn't internally seem to work with.

Disclaimer: Please don't do this. Please do this only if in a very odd situation - and try to alter the situation in other ways before doing this. I did this to cope with odd code that could not be changed at the time of asking - not to provide a way to proliferate more odd code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a copy of a python module at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170949/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-python-module-at-runtime)

Comment: @ThorSummoner yes i think so, with a pretty good top answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it personally but it seems that [Exocet](http://washort.twistedmatrix.com/2011/01/introducing-exocet.html) library may help.

Comment: I like the use of a library that handles this - likely to be far better than tinkering directly with sys, and I can always report/fix bugs if there are any.

Answer (score 16):

Just remove the module from [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
>>> import sys
>>> import mod as m1
>>> m1.x = 1
>>> del sys.modules['mod']
>>> import mod as m2
>>> m2.x = 2
>>> m1.x
1
```

Comment: does this make all classes in python redundant? (since modules can be used instead)

Comment: Classes and modules both have namespaces, but the similarities end there. For example, modules are not callable, so they cannot replace classes.

Comment: cheers. for my purposes i think i can completely go without classes. the only reason i normally use classes is for extending base functionality. i think i can still do this with modules, but i just have to explicitly invoke the "child" module or "parent" module as required. its slightly more thought effort, but then its useful to think where the invoked function lives anyway...

Comment: @mulllhausen Please don't. I did this to cope with odd code - not to provide a way to proliferate more odd code.

Answer (score 3):

You can try by fooling sys.modules

```
import badmodule as badmod1

import sys
del sys.modules['badmodule']

import badmodule as badmod2
```

If this works or not of course depends on what the bad module is doing...

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to make two copies of the module and import them separately. For example, take your module `thingabobber` and make two copies named `thingabobber1` and `thingabobber2`. Then just:

```
import thingabobber1, thingabobber2
```

If this isn't feasible, delete the module from `sys.modules` after initially importing it so you get a second copy on the second import.

```
import sys

import thingabobber as thingabobber1
del sys.modules["thingabobber"]
import thingabobber as thingabobber2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by importing the module via different paths.
That is - if in your sys.path you have two different dotted routes to the module, the module cache will create two different instances of the module with different symbol trees, globals and so on.

This can be used to have multiple versions of a library also.

Beware that it will lead to exceptions not being caught (as you are trying to catch the wrong symbol).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this with binary (so) submodules, but that procedure failed.