# Are there programming languages with non-singleton modules?

Tags: programming-languages, import, module

Are there any programming languages with module import routines that have the following behavior:

```
import lib as x
import lib as y
x == y # False
```

This is in Python syntax; although Python would return `True` from the comparison. I don't know of a language that has this kind of behavior. Is there case where this is explicitly a "language feature" and not [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985617/get-2-isolated-instances-of-a-python-module)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CommonJS modules](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) and [NodeJS modules](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/modules.html) offer such a case, where every import/require returns an object which is assigned to a variable and then the features are accessed via that reference.

[Newspeak modules(PDF)](http://bracha.org/newspeak-modules.pdf) offer a more research-oriented take where the modules are instantiated with parameters and then assigned to a variable/local slot which offers even more flexibility but obviously Newspeak isn't commonly-used.