# Disable copying file attributes?

Tags: python, linux, filesystems

I'm working with a file system mounted on linux where `cp -a` always fails as not permitted. Is there a way to disable `shutil.copystat` and `shutil.copymode` in Python?

I have the below workaround but it's a bit ridiculous.

```
import shutil
def nothin(*args, **kwargs):
    return


shutil.copymode = nothin
shutil.copystat = nothin
```

Comment: Why do you need to disable exactly `shutil`? `cp -a` could also be called with `subprocess`, for example.

Comment: @martineau and what could be the purpose of disabling it if so?

Comment: So, anything that tries to edit a file date will fail on this drive. I want to avoid that. shutil is used all over and I'd like to be able to just move my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function overriding is a usual practice for python (at least for Django Rest Framework for example).

But! the main problem in your code is the scope. When you overriding module function, the new function will be used in all other parts of the code.

See this example:

```py
import shutil

print('first try')

try:
  print(shutil.copymode("a", "b"))
except Exception as e:
  print(e)

shutil.copymode = lambda x,y: x + y

print('second try')

print(shutil.copymode("a", "b"))

import shutil

print('third try after re-import')

try:
  print(shutil.copymode("a", "b"))
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

```
first try
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a'
second try
ab
third try after re-import
ab
```

`shutil` already has modified `copymode` function even if it is re-imported. And that may be super painful for someone who will try to use `shutil` for this code in future.

So I recommend to import `shutil` as separated copy object. So changes will be affected only for one current file (thanks to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11285504/13946204)):

```py
import importlib.util
import sys
SPEC_OS = importlib.util.find_spec('shutil')
custom_shutil = importlib.util.module_from_spec(SPEC_OS)
SPEC_OS.loader.exec_module(custom_shutil)
sys.modules['custom_shutil'] = custom_shutil

custom_shutil.copymode = lambda x, y: x + y

# or
# setattr(custom_shutil, 'copymode', lambda x, y: x + y)

print('first try')

print(custom_shutil.copymode("a", "b"))

import shutil

print('second try')

try:
  print(shutil.copymode("a", "b"))
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

```
first try
ab
second try
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a'
```

However `copymode` not just check for a copy mode but also check if file exists. Skipping of this checks may cause unexpected behaviour in future.

Comment: Ooooh, that's a really good point about checking if the file exists. Will need to replicate that behavior. And am trying to break it all throughout code, not just for one file.