# How to import '.so' file twice in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am trying to use pybind11 to write python binding for an existing C++ project. It generates a '.so' file which can be `import`ed in python.

The problem is that the C++ code uses a lot of global variables for states. So if I want to have 2 seperate instances, I need to somehow import the module twice.

So far, the following methods do not work, assuming the file is `my_module.so`

1. naive method

```py
import my_module as m1
import my_module as m2
assert m1 is not m2 # fail!
```

2. method from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170949/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-python-module-at-runtime)

```py
def load():
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec('my_module')
    m = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(m)
    return m

m1 = load()
m2 = load()
assert m1 is not m2 # fail!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem, I come up with a dirty but working solution.

If you want to have `n` copies, then you have to make n copies of the `.so` file, say `my_module_*.so`.

Then use the following code to import them.

```py
import importlib

modules=[]
for i in range(n):
    loader = importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader('my_module', f'/path/to/my_module_{i}.so')
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
    my_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    loader.exec_module(my_module)
    modules.append(my_module)
```

Note that for clarity the modules are not added to 'global namespace', i.e. `sys.modules`.

**P.S. If you have a better solution, maybe without the need of copying files, please post it below, thanks!**